# ConcurrentModificationException in LiveData Android

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-livedata

There is one background service that provides a stream of data and updates the live data.
We receive an exception when iterating through the arraylist. We got a concurrent modification exception while iterating through the arraylist. How we can solve this problem?

`val _receivedCommandList = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<String>>() val receivedCommandList: LiveData<ArrayList<String>> get() = _receivedCommandList`

```
homeViewModel.command.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
    binding.descriptionText.text = ""
    var cmd = ""
    for (command in it){
        cmd += "${command.trim()}\n\n"
    }
    binding.descriptionText.text = cmd
})
```

The mutable live data (_receivedCommandList) will be updated inside the service when onCharacteristicChanged() in BLE.

```
repository?.let {
       val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss ")
       val command = "\n${sdf.format(Date())} A -> B = $cmd\n"
                        commandList.add(0,command)
       it._receivedCommandList.postValue(commandList)
}
```

We tried to put delay while iterating through list, it works fine when list is small but when list becomes large it gives exception again.

Comment: "We got a concurrent modification exception while iterating through the arraylist" -- this means something is modifying the *same* `ArrayList` object while you are iterating over that. Do not do this. Your question does not show how you are creating the `ArrayList` or how you are putting it in the `MutableLiveData`, so we cannot comment on this.

Comment: I think you'll have issues with this design, livedata loves to misbehave when handling mutable data (which your arraylist is). A crude workaround would be to always put a copy of your list in livedata so you're not affected by modification of source. But personally I think your problem could be solved by migrating to `Flow` that will emit each command separately and `.reduce` them in view to accumulate displayed message. Unless you're removing items from your received command list because that'd require more consideration.

Comment: @Pawel Thank you, I think Flow will be the better option as Live data misbehaves with list data.